# make: *** No rule to make target

Tags: c, makefile

Thanks for the responses. I found that this worked — I don't know why though.

```
all: $(OUT)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(INCLUDES)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
        ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)
        cp DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.h ../include

.PHONY: clean
```

---

Below is a makefile I have. I keep getting the error make: `*** No rule to make target` but cannot see what is wrong in this case. The ".c" files exist in the current directory. I'm not sure why makefile cannot see them — can you explain?

```
DimeFileAppsAuth/src> ls
db_get_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.c     db_reset_query_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.c  Makefile
db_add_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.c     db_print_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.c  db_update_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.c
db_delete_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.c  db_reset_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.c
```

---

#### Running the make

```
DimeFileAppsAuth/src> make
make: *** No rule to make target `../obj/db_add_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o', needed by `../lib/lib_dime_file_apps.a'.  Stop.
```

---

#### The Makefile

```
# clear out all suffixes
.SUFFIXES:
# list only those we use
.SUFFIXES: .o .c

# define a suffix rule for .c -> .o
.c.o :
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

FILE_DIVERSION=$(IMG_PROJ_HOME)/dime/basics/BasicsLink

INC_DIR =../include
LIB_DIR =../lib
OBJ_DIR =../obj
BIN_DIR =../bin
CUR_DIR = .

OUT = $(LIB_DIR)/lib_dime_file_apps.a
BIN_OUT = $(BIN_DIR)/test_run

# include directories
INCLUDES = -I$(INC_DIR)  -I$(FILE_DIVERSION)/include  -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/public -I/usr/local/include

# library paths
LIBS = -L$(LIB_DIR) -ldime_direct  -L$(FILE_DIVERSION)/lib -loutput_files -lquerylib -lsql_common -lsql_common -L$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib -lclntsh -L$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib `cat $(ORACLE_HOME)/lib/sysliblist` -L/usr/local/lib -lm

CC=gcc
CCFLAGS=-w -O2 -unused-variable -Wall -fPIC  -c -g -rdynamic


_DEPS = DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(INC_DIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = db_add_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_delete_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_get_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_get_SEQ_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_print_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_reset_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_reset_query_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_special_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_update_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

_BIN = db_add_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_delete_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_get_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_get_SEQ_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_print_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_reset_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_reset_query_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_special_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o db_update_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o test_this.o
BIN = $(patsubst %,$(BIN_DIR)/%,$(_BIN))

all: $(OUT)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(INCLUDES)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
        ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)
        cp DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.h ../include

exec: $(BIN) $(OUT)
        $(CC) -o $(BIN_OUT) $(BIN) $(LIBS)
        rm $(BIN_DIR)/*.o

.PHONY: clean
```

Comment: Your rule for creating object files does not take directory prefixes into account.

Answer (score 1):

The make error occurs when it comes to this line "$(OUT): $(OBJ)". Please check whether the file named "db_add_DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.o" exists in the directory "../obj"

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured this out and made a replacement with the following items below. I dont know why it worked though :-|
all: $(OUT)
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(INCLUDES)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
        ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)
        cp DIMEFILEAPPSAUTH.h ../include